# Why use HTTP verbs?

Tags: asp.net, .net, http

Since verbs target a URL like server.domain/getallrecords or server.domain/delete1record or something similar. And getallrecords, delete1record are specifically designed for specific purposes, why do we need Verbs here ?

Whats the difference between a get call to

```
server.domain/getallrecords or 
server.domain/delete1record
```

or a put (or post or delete) call to any of the above URL ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you go the *RPC way* it seems like HTTP verbs are useless.

HTTP verbs are a good companion of REST-style HTTP services, because resource-oriented URIs won't contain an action identifier but a resource.

For example, `server.domain/getallrecords` would be `server.domain/records` and if you perform a request to this resource using HTTP/GET, resource will be mapped to a server method which will return all records, if you perform the same request using HTTP/POST, it would create a new record, and so on.

You need to decide: [RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) or [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer), and depending on this, you'll find HTTP verbs useful or not. I would suggest you that using HTTP verbs is a good way of using a well-known protocol - HTTP - with predefined verbs, instead of inventing your own ones. But again, it depends on your own thoughts, preferences and requirements.

Comment: Allow me to add to this answer that your default cross domain reference protections by default will prevent Verbs such as `DELETE`, `POST` and `PUT` from being accessible. If you use `GET` for everything, a malicious site could use code such as `<img src="http://server.domain/delete1record" />` to trigger a delete attempt by all visiting users. If one of your users which is authorized to do so visits this site, then you could be in trouble.

Comment: @tom.dietrich BTW the scenario of removing records using `GET` verb is just a design flaw, isn't it?

Comment: I don't think ASP.NET prevents cross domain `GET` requests by default, but I might be mistaken. I would definitely suggest that using `GET` for anything that is not simply retrieving data is a bad idea.

Comment: @tom.dietrich I've dropped all my comments. Now I know they were part of an useless discussion which doesn't add any value to my answer and OP's question. Now it's up to you to do so, because your comments don't help future visitors. Add your own answer explaining your own throughts, this is how SO works.

Answer (score 1):

In a rest API, say you have 4 endpoints for an inventory API

1. is for creation of an item
2. is for modification (edit operation) of an item(s)
3. is for deletion of an item
4. is for view of an item
   The API endpoint would look like these:

   servername.domain/createItem

   servername.domain/editItem

   servername.domain/deleteItem

   servername.domain/viewItems

but if we use verbs, we will only need 1 endpoint, since the endpoint can figure out what operation to do given the HTTP verb

servername.domain/inventory

if that endpoint receives a GET, its the /viewItems
if that endpoint receives a POST, its the /createItems
if that endpoint receives a PUT, its the /editItems
if that endpoint receives a DELETE, its the /deleteItems